# Save JSON file into structured database with Python

Tags: python, sql, json, database, data-warehouse

I am building a warehouse consisting of data that's found from a public facing API.  In order to store & analyze the data, I'd like to save the JSON files I'm receiving into a structured SQL database.  Meaning, all the JSON contents shouldn't be contained in 1 column.  The contents should be parsed out and stored in various other tables in a relational database.

From a process standpoint, I need to do the following:

1. Call API
2. Receive JSON
3. Parse JSON file
4. Insert/Update table(s) in a SQL database

(This process will be repeated hundreds and hundreds of times)

Is there a best practice to accomplish this - from either a process or resource standpoint?  I'd like to do this in Python if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question unfortunately is too broad. This is not a tutorial site or open-ended discussion forum but a Q/A on specific issues. Come back with actual trial/error on a use case and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: what is your DB ? how good with python are you ? how many table you'll need ? what are the load you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `json.dumps(json_value)` to convert your JSON object into a JSON string that can be put into an sql database.

Comment: But would putting a dictionary in SQL DB is the recommended practice when the same is fetched and further processed